# Nautilus slow to load on first attempt

Tags: nautilus, error-handling

After every restart or shutdown, nautilus takes about 10 sec to load.Once loaded, it will start quickly next time.
I started `nautilus` from terminal with sudo access and the error was

```
** (nautilus:4298): CRITICAL **: nautilus_menu_provider_get_background_items: assertion `NAUTILUS_IS_MENU_PROVIDER (provider)' failed
```

I tried the solutions given in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/147682/184942), they don't help.

Is there any fix for this error?

Comment: Could be version related, what version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: @Requist `Ubuntu12.10` with `GNOME nautilus 3.4.2`

Comment: Then why not first try to use your time to update to 13.10, the issue might be long solved? A simple sudo do-release-upgrade is done in 15minutes.

Comment: @Requist 15 minutes? that maybe possible in Us or europe.Here in a semi urban town in India, considering my budget, it will take 15 hours.Anyway, I'm not going to use this computer any longer than july.That's time when I'll leave this city for further studies.

Comment: Ok, I see your problem. Maybe something useful here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60227/nautilus-is-extremely-slow
Further you can do a self-check by executing nautilus -c
And have it start in a different folder by doing nautilus /boot

Comment: @Requist but where is the **Enable Assistive Technologies** option in 12.10?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13148/discussion-between-requist-and-aditya-patil)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same CRITICAL error, and it was caused by the Python extension. So I solved uninstalling the **python-nautilus** package, that was installed as a dependence of Insync (that I'm no longer using in this machine).

```
sudo apt-get purge python-nautilus
```